# Cannot login to my github account - MFA not working

Tags: github

My github account seems to be locked.

1. I have 2FA and the code (from my phone - google authenticator) is not working.
2. I have saved my recovery codes (16 of them) safely in my lastpass during account creation and they are also not working.
3. There was an option to use "previously used personal access tokens" and that is also not working (It is in my keychain - so no way of losing it).

Don't know what to do.

Can somebody help me please.

Comment: Have you contacted Github? It is always worth a try.

Comment: I did, waiting for reply

Comment: Welcome to the club.
Try to contact with GitHub support:
https://support.github.com/contact/account?contact[type]=account&flow=2fa
But probably it will not help. It didn't help in my case.